# regex idiom for excluding word while matching other conditions

Tags: regex, sed, grep, regex-lookarounds

The problem is as follows. I need to match every line that:

- starts with `<`
- doesn't have the tag `<s>` inside
- ends with the tag `</s>`

Examples:

```
<div> blablabla </div> blablabla </s>
<div> blablabla </div> <s> blablabla </s>
```

I've been trying by placing a negative lookahead and a wildcard

```
^<((?!<s>).)*</s>$
```

and have also thought about [this trick](//stackoverflow.com/a/23589204/2420152), but no success so far. I am also aware of

```
grep -v
```

but I would like to have a pure regex idiom that I can then use in other contexts (like sed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
^(?!.*<s>)<.*</s>$
```

**Explanation**:

```
^          # the beginning of the string
(?!        # look ahead to see if there is not:
  .*       #   any character except \n (0 or more times)
  <s>      #   '<s>'
)          # end of look-ahead
<          # '<'
.*         # any character except \n (0 or more times)
</s>       # '</s>'
$          # before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/fB7iO8/8)

Using grep you can use the `-P` option which interprets the pattern as a Perl regular expression.

```
grep -P '^(?!.*<s>)<.*</s>$'
```

You may also consider using the alternation operator in context placing what you want to exclude on the left, ( *saying throw this away, it's garbage* ) and place what you want to match in a capturing group on the right side.

```
^.*<s>.*|(<.*</s>)$
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/cH5yO2/1)

Answer (score 2):

You mention the `grep -v` approach but want an "idiom that I can then use in other contexts (like sed)."  Actually, the `grep -v` approach also works for `sed`.  It also keeps it quite simple by avoiding all fancy (and often not supported) regex constructs.  It is implemented as follows:

```
sed -n '/<s>/n; /^<.*<\/s>/p' file
```

Examining it one piece at a time:

- `-n`

  This tells `sed` not to print anything unless explicitly asked.
- `/<s>/n;`

  This tells `sed` to skip over any line with `<s>`.  This command is the analog to `grep -v`.  (In `sed`, the `n` command means skip to the next line.)
- `/^<.*<\/s>/p`

  This selects the lines that you want and prints them.

#### Mac OSX Note

If I recall correctly, the OSX `sed` (and probably other non-GNU seds) do not support commands combined with semicolons.  The work around is to use `-e`:

```
sed -n -e '/<s>/n' -e '/^<.*<\/s>/p' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You've almost reached your answer.

```
^(?!.*<s>)<.*?</s>
```

---

What your current pattern did was search for string starting with `<`, but are not immediately followed by `<s>`. Whereas, the `<s>` tag can appear anywhere in your texts.

Answer (score 0):

Using the trick you commented about could help you.

If you use this regex:

```
.*<s>.*|(.*<\/s>)
```

You will have the line that you want in the capturing groups.

Here you have a **[working example](http://regex101.com/r/eM0hB7/1)**

[image]